# how to find first index of any number except 0 in python list?

Tags: python

I have a list that contain 0 and some other numbers, how can I find the first index of a number that is not 0 ?

for example in this list `list1 = [0,0,0,0,4,3,2,0,3]` how can I find the index of 4?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `enumerate` to iterate over the indices and values. Then use `next` to stop upon finding the first non-zero value. If `StopIteration` was thrown, the list contained no non-zero values, so do whatever error handling you'd like there.

```
def first_non_zero(values):
    try:
        return next(idx for idx, value in enumerate(values) if value != 0)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Examples

```
>>> list1 = [0,0,0,0,4,3,2,0,3]
>>> first_non_zero(list1)
4
>>> first_non_zero([0,0,0])
>>>      # None
```

Comment: I used `next(filter(lambda x: x[1], enumerate(list1)))[0]` but your solution is more readable.

Comment: `if value != 0` is already redundant

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] != 0:
        print(i)
        break
```

or specifically 4

```
list1.index(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be:

```
list1.index([value for value in list1 if value!=0][0])
```

Of course this only works if you have nonzero elements in your list. If you want to deal with all cases, you might want to use following function:

```
def first_non_zero_index(list1):
    for idx, value in enumerate(list1):
        if value!=0:
            return idx
    return None
```

And throw list directly at it as: `first_non_zero_index(list1)` which returns `4`

Comment: Thanks Cory! I updated it. I previously left handling those cases out as question explicitly mentioned that there are non-zero elements present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This simple line:

```
list(map(bool, list1)).index(True)
```

```
4
```

All non-zero values evaluate to `True`, so when converting all elements to boolean, you just need to find the first `True`.

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = [0,0,0,0,4,3,2,0,3]
for i in set(list1):
    if i:
        print("Index of {} is {}".format(i,list1.index(i)))
```